# MongoDb Query using C# for date time

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am working on MongoDb using C# drivers. I want query the mongoDb database to find out the row which has EventDate is greater than 13 months from todays date.

my MongoDb has structure something similar to below:

EventDate is of datatype : DateTime

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("525239e3e9374f1c3ce4123b"),
   "RowId" : 41133552,
   "EventDate" : ISODate("2013-08-19T00:00:28Z"),
   "Product" : "supporttool",
   "Language" : "en",
   "GUID" : "67cd73d4-36bc-4c9f-9a4c-144b38d4e928",
}
```

Please can anyone help me out to get the MongoCollection for data with event date older than 13 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to it, but this would be the one with LINQ extension method syntax:

```
MongoDatabase db = YourMongoDatabaseObject;
var cursor = db.GetCollection<YourClass>("yourClass").Find(
   Query<YourClass>.LT(p => p.EventDate, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-13));
```

This will return a cursor to all documents in the `"yourClass"` collection that have an an `EventDate` less than 13 months ago and will deserialize them as instances of `YourClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the query. I am trying to delete those record which I got in above query. PLEASE CAN UPDATE YOUR ANSWER.

Comment: to remove records, just change `Find` to `Remove`

Comment: could you explain to me what the 'p' is?? I'm still new to mongo and linq

Comment: @M009: Yes, but not in a comment to a one year old question. Please create a new question for it.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-13)` is a good example and works perfect.